# Session Disconnection

Tags: security, ssl, session, networking, tcp

Sorry if this question is naive.

I have tried searching around on google for this but no joy yet.

Scenario:
The TCP session has been established between client & server, due to some reasons session was interrupted & terminated.
Now, during the reestablishment of the session, will the past session be resumed, or the new session be established.
If new session established, why?
If last session resumes, why & how?

Please help, if there are any resources to get a hang on this will be really helpful.

Comment: You may want to learn more about the Internet layers, and what happens at each of them, taking as example HTTP over TCP over IP. Then add TLS into the mix. And then look at QUIC which is similar in features with TLS but different in implementation (since it uses UDP at its core, nor TCP) but also features, because here indeed participants can change IP addresses and the flows are preserved because identified by something else than IP addresses and ports.

Answer (score 1):

TCP doesn't have a "session" concept, and of course also doesn't have "session reestablishment".

TCP has "connections", and each connection has no relation whatsoever with any previous connection.